# Grow-Only GridSplitter

Tags: wpf, xaml, resize, gridsplitter, wpf-grid

I have a pretty simple requirement that I can't seem to find a solution for. Take a look at my sample XAML code:

```
<Grid ShowGridLines="True" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="5">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition MinHeight="100"/>
        <RowDefinition MinHeight="100"/>
        <RowDefinition MinHeight="100"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Grid.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="GridSplitter">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
            <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Bottom"/>
            <Setter Property="Height" Value="1"/>
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Black"/>
        </Style>
    </Grid.Resources>

    <GridSplitter/>
    <GridSplitter Grid.Row="1"/>
    <GridSplitter Grid.Row="2"/>
</Grid>
```

I have three rows that start out with a height of 100. I want the user to be able to drag the edge of any row to make it taller, so I put a [`GridSplitter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.gridsplitter) in every row.

The problem is:

> The GridSplitter control redistributes space between rows or columns
>   in a Grid, without changing the dimensions of the Grid. For example,
>   when a GridSplitter resizes two columns, the ActualWidth property of
>   one column is increased while at the same time the ActualWidth
>   property of the other column is decreased by the same amount.

The above XAML doesn't work, none of the rows change size when dragged, because the `GridSplitter` is trying to take height from another row and add it to the one being resized. Since none of the rows can get any smaller (`MinHeight="100"`), nothing happens.

But I don't *want* to take height from the other rows. I want to increase the size of one row independently, which will in turn change the overall height of the `Grid`. If I drag the middle row to be 50px taller, I want to have that row be 150px while the other two remain 100px, making the overall grid 350px.

Is there any setting on the `GridSplitter` I'm missing that will allow this? Or is there some other control I can use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you're expecting?

```xml
<StackPanel>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding ActualHeight, 
                      ElementName=grid, 
                      StringFormat='Grid Actual Height: {0}'}" FontSize="30"/>
    <Grid x:Name="grid" Background="Aqua">
        <Grid.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="GridSplitter">
                <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
                <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
                <Setter Property="Height" Value="5"/>
                <Setter Property="ShowsPreview" Value="False"/>
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Black"/>
            </Style>
            <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                <Setter Property="Text" 
                        Value="{Binding ActualHeight, 
                                RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=StackPanel}, 
                                StringFormat='Row Actual Height: {0}'}"/>
                <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="30"/>
                <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
            </Style>
        </Grid.Resources>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition MinHeight="100" Height="100" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition MinHeight="100" Height="100" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition MinHeight="100" Height="100" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Background="Tan">
            <TextBlock />
        </StackPanel>
        <GridSplitter Grid.Row="1"/>
        <StackPanel Grid.Row="2" Background="Brown">
            <TextBlock />
        </StackPanel>
        <GridSplitter Grid.Row="3"/>
        <StackPanel Grid.Row="4" Background="Bisque">
            <TextBlock />
        </StackPanel>
        <GridSplitter Grid.Row="5" ResizeBehavior="PreviousAndCurrent"/>
    </Grid>
</StackPanel>
```

The problem is with the way you're adding `GridSplitter` to your `Grid` control. You can get more detail on how this works at [GridSplitter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.gridsplitter) documentation. This also includes how to use [ResizeBehavior](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.gridsplitter.resizebehavior); which i'd used to get it working for last row

Comment: Yes it is! The only thing missing is the bottom row being able to grow as well. Could you add a little explanation of how you got that to work? I haven't quite figured it out yet by looking at your code.

Comment: @KeithStein I'd updated the answer with support for bottom row as well.  Also, added links for MS Docs; which explains this in detail.

Comment: Thanks. Apparently what actually makes your code work is setting `GridRow.Height`. I have no idea why that fixes it, but if you take my original code and just add `Height="100"` to every row it works perfectly. Except for the last row, but I can just add an extra empty row with `Height="Auto"` at the bottom to fix that.